# How RAM is distributed among processes in MPI?

Tags: parallelism, mpi, multiprocessor

For example for a 4GB RAM and 2 processes, each process will take 2 GB of memory?

Comment: What is MPI?  You may have to add more detail, for this to be answerable.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor, they probably mean the parallel programming library/API: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/mpi/info